# Difference Intel CPU: i9-7960X and i9-9960X

Tags: processor, intel

I'm wondering about the pricing. I'm about to decide my next Intel CPU and according to [cpu-world.com](http://www.cpu-world.com/info/Intel/processor-number.html)

[image: img]

the i9-9960X has a higher frequency and otherwise the same properties as the i9-7960X. However, the 9960X is currently available for 860 Euros, while the 7960X requires almost 1700 Euros. What am I missing?

In general, I was considering to buy a 16 core Intel CPU. I currently have an 8 core i7-5960X which served me well during the last years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question seems to be mostly about the price difference, and not about technical differences between the two generations of CPUs, I will limit my answer to the former.
Somewhere between these two generations of Intel CPUs, AMD happended. Their Threadripper CPUs and Ryzen CPUs with high core counts more or less forced retailers to lower their prices for Intel X299 CPUs, particularly the Skylake-X lineup. https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-skylake-x-price-cut-cascade-lake-x

Then with the current 10th generation of X299 CPUs (e.g. I9-10980XE) Intel  lowered MSRP for their CPUs significantly. See https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-cascade-lake-x-pricing-availability-launch-specifications-10th-generation,40526.html

So don't let the price difference fool you into thinking the older 7th gen CPUs are that much better than current 10th gen Cascade-Lake X CPUs, or 9th gen CPUs. They just did not get the price cuts, because they are too old to be relevant in today's retail market.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer! I was aware of AMD making a serious push at the CPU market, but I haven't realized it forced Intel to such large price-cuts. Also, I considered buying one of the i9-10XXX but the ones I liked are simply not available in Germany. I checked with 4 online distributors and no one had the i9-10980XE available.

Comment: Some sites in Germany (e.g. Cyberport) state that the 10980XE will be available on the January 12th. Caseking claims it will be available within a few business days, but they charge a pretty hefty price of 1249€. So the waiting game might be over soon, albeit at prices higher than Intels MSRP.